# Configure Visual Studio "Setup Project" via code

Tags: .net, visual-studio, installation, project

In my solution I have added a Setup Project to deploy my application. For some reason I want to configure it pragmatically not through VS wizards, that is, set “Project Output”, needed assemblies etc. via code. Also I need to make final setup file, again via code.

Thanks for your kind help.

Regards,
Behzad

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [WIX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wix/)? It may take longer to setup what you need initially, but will be more flexible in long term.

Answer (score 0):

While not strictly an answer to your question, the Github project CLIDE is a command line utility that simplifies creating and managing Visual Studio projects, and makes it easier to manage and build projects using only the compiler (csc.exe) and msbuild.exe . Use it to create a test project that does what you need, and you should be able to figure out the rest from the files it creates.

https://github.com/remi/clide